# In $S_4$ describe all the leftcosets of the subgroup $D_4$

Tags: group-theory, symmetric-groups, dihedral-groups

How can I describe the left and right cosets of $D_4$ I know that $D_4 $ is

$
\begin{array}{ll}
\rho_{0}=\left(\begin{array}{llll}
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4
\end{array}\right) & \mu_{1}=\left(\begin{array}{llll}
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
2 & 1 & 4 & 3
\end{array}\right) \\
\rho_{1}=\left(\begin{array}{llll}
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
2 & 3 & 4 & 1
\end{array}\right) & \mu_{2}=\left(\begin{array}{llll}
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
4 & 3 & 2 & 1
\end{array}\right) \\
\rho_{2}=\left(\begin{array}{llll}
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
3 & 4 & 1 & 2
\end{array}\right) & \delta_{1}=\left(\begin{array}{llll}
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
3 & 2 & 1 & 4
\end{array}\right) \\
\rho_{3}=\left(\begin{array}{llll}
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
4 & 1 & 2 & 3
\end{array}\right) & \delta_{2}=\left(\begin{array}{llll}
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
1 & 4 & 3 & 2
\end{array}\right)
\end{array}
$

and there are 3 right and 3 left cosets, but how can i describe it?

Comment: What've *you* tried? Please add anything relevant to the question body with an [edit] instead of replying in the comments.

Comment: You may also find it more efficient to express your permutations using [cycle notation](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/PermutationCycle.html)